# The equation $x_1+x_2 + \cdots + x_{251}=708$ and $y_1+y_2 + \cdots + y_{n}=708$ have the same # of solutions $n \neq251$ find n.

Tags: combinatorics

> The equation
>   $$x_1+x_2 + \cdots + x_{251}=708$$
>   Has a certain # of solutions in positive integers 
>   $$x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_{251}$$
>   Now the equation 
>   $$y_1+y_2 + \cdots + y_{n}=708$$ 
>   also has the same number of positive integer solutions 
>   $$y_1,y_2, \ldots, y_n$$ 
>   Where $$n \neq251$$ 
>   What is $$n$$

Looking at the stars and bars page it mentions that  $${m \choose k}={m \choose m-k}$$ So then why wont $n$ just be $457$? Where $m=707$ and $k=250$

Thanks for any help. I don't really know any combinatorics just trying out problems and looking up information and I don't think I quite understand the stars and bars that well.

Comment: Are the equations "$x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_n = 708$ and $y_1+y_2+y_3+\cdots+y_n = 708$" or are they "$x_1+x_2x_3\cdots x_n = 708$ and $y_1+y_2y_3\cdots y_n = 708$"? I assume the first, but it isn't clear from just the title.

Comment: They are the first two mentioned(the sums) the one's underneath are the integer solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the simpler cases, $x_1=708$ has a single solution, and $\sum_{j=1}^{n}=y_j=708,\quad n\neq 1$ has a single solution iff $n=708$, and $y_j=1$ for all $j$.

Now let's look at $x_1+x_2=708$ which has 707 solutions (a single solution for each choice of $x_1=1..707$, for $\sum y_j$ we will now get $n=707$ in which we have to choose the single $j$ for which $y_j=2$.

So basically we can already feel that $m+n=709$ (where $m$ is the number of $x$'s and $n$ is the number of $y$'s).

Your reasoning therefore seems to be correct, but you are missing a 1 somewhere.

Comment: Oh so it would just be $458$ I just forgot to convert it back